# Getting opencv to work (segfault)

Tags: c, opencv

I'm debugging this small program in Linux compiling the code with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o videoHandler videoHandler.c
```

And when I run it I get this output:

```
minscanline 1
minscanline 1
minscanline 1
minscanline 1
Video loaded succesfully
minscanline 1
Segmentation fault
```

All I really care about is that while loop, cause I need to get the individual frames of the movie file. Any ideas?

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define HEIGHT 480
#define WIDTH 640

// Position the video at a specific frame number position
//cvSetCaptureProperty(video, CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, next_frame);

// Convert the frame to a smaller size (WIDTH x HEIGHT)
//cvResize(img, thumb, CV_INTER_AREA);

int main(void){

    CvCapture *video;
    IplImage *image;
    CvMat *thumb;
    CvMat *encoded;

    // Open the video file.
    video = cvCaptureFromFile("sample.avi");
    if (!video) {
        // The file doesn't exist or can't be captured as a video file.
        printf("Video could not load\n");
    }else{
        printf("Video loaded succesfully\n");
        // Obtain the next frame from the video file
        while ( image = cvQueryFrame(video) ) {
            printf("Inside loop\n");
            //If next frame doesn't exist, Video ended

            thumb = cvCreateMat(HEIGHT, WIDTH, CV_8UC3);

            // Encode the frame in JPEG format with JPEG quality 30%.
            const static int encodeParams[] = { CV_IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY, 30 };
            encoded = cvEncodeImage(".jpeg", thumb, encodeParams);
            // After the call above, the encoded data is in encoded->data.ptr
            // and has a length of encoded->cols bytes.

            namedWindow( "Display Image", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
            imshow( "Display Image", encoded );

            printf("Frame retrieved, length: %s\n", encoded->cols);
        }


        // Close the video file
        cvReleaseCapture(&video);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't immediately see what the problem is, but here's what you can do to help yourself (or update the question to have better chance of getting help here):

**1st** compile with warnings enabled:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o videoHandler videoHandler.c
```

Then fix any warning you get (or edit question to add them if you can't figure them out).

**2nd** run your program under debugger and see which line triggers the segfault. Add that, as well as relevant variable values (either by adding debug prints or by examining them with debugger) to the question too, if you still can't figure it out.

**3rd** if still not solved, run [*valgrind*](http://valgrind.org) on your application (if you are on Windows, then install a Linux VM and run it under it, I generally use VirtualBox + latest available Lubuntu virtual disk image).

Actually, you should try [*valgrind*](http://valgrind.org) even if you solve this issue, and see what warnings it gives, and if any of those are actually bugs you should fix (it may also give false positives, even a lot of them with some libs).

Comment: Thanks man, I'll take it into account. UPDATE: It's partially working.

Comment: @PatricioJerí One more thing to check: verify that video plays with a video player application, and also test your app with another video, preferably with different encoding. It's not impossible that there is a bug triggered by invalid video file or even valid but poorly tested video codec on valid file, which causes that Segfault.

Comment: The last printf() with %s to represent an Integer is wrong. This is why you are getting a segfault. Change %s with %d. Regards

Comment: @CesarOrtiz Well spotted!. Though, that should have been picked up by `-Wall` of the **1st** step in my answer, if @PatricioJeri indeed did that.